# Exporting just one feature to KML

Tags: qgis, google-earth, layer-to-kml

I'm trying to export just one polygon from QGIS as a .kml file, so that I can open it in Google Earth Pro without seeing any other layers. Whenever I export it as a .kml file and open it in Google Earth, it's opening all the layers from my QGIS project, even though I didn't export those (to my knowledge!) in the .kml file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

My project has Google Earth Satellite as a base map, then a scanned in (and georeferenced) map, and a polygon depicting an area of interest. It's just the polygon that I would like to export as a kml file if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you export the desired polygon as a separate .kml file. You can use the *selection tool* to select the polygon (it will be highlighted in a bright yellow color), then right-click the layer on the "layers" area and "export > save selected features as...". If you have correctly selected a laye, the option should be available to you.

[image]

Then, try importing the new .kml file to Google Earth.